# Change text-fill-color with scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

How change text-fill-color with scroll. On start text should be white. When scroll is lower text should be transparent (in background is image).
I know, that must change text-fill-color from rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) to rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)

Code:

```
    var bg = document.querySelector('.shadower');
var text = document.querySelector('.clip-text-bg');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var scroll = window.scrollY;
  var percent = (scroll / height).toFixed(2);

  bg.style.opacity = Math.min(percent, .7);
  text.style.opacity = Math.max(1 - (percent * 2), 0);
})
```

http://codepen.io/Bakr1/pen/EWXdPG

Comment: which text? The large lorem ipsum passage?

Comment: Yes, lorem ipsum is ok ;)